# How to take a simple integer matrix as input in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I want to take a simple matrix as input in a 2-D array, but get a Runtime `Error - NZEC` error.
Matrix -

```
1 2  
3 4
```

my input code -

```
for i in range(2):
    a[i]=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using `i` as the loop variable and the list comprehension variable at the same time
2. You have not declared `a` (visibly). Declare `a = []` and use `list.append`.

---

Try this:

```
a = []
for _ in range(2):
    a.append([int(i) for i in input().split()])
```

Declare `a` to be empty initially. Then call `a.append` to append new sublists to your list.